# Merge Replication between two Embedded Databases?

Tags: replication

I have an application that uses SQL Server CE 3.5.  I am trying to expand the database to have a remote database accessible from various locations.  I will need both the local (which might or might not have consistent internet connections) and the remote databases to be able to sync with one another and to be able to send and receive updates from the other database upon internet connection.

Is it possible to replicate an embedded database such as SQL Server CE with another embedded database or do you have to set up a server for this functionality?  If not, what would be a recommended server database to use (preferably to be set up on a cloud server)?

Thanks,
Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding (I haven't worked with this in over a year) is that "merge replication" requires a sql server instance to act as a publisher. If you want to only have an SQL CE database at each end, you need to write your own code with [sync framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753) (if you see articles on "[sync services](http://keithelder.net/2007/09/23/sync-services-for-sql-server-compact-edition-3-5-in-visual/)" they are using the sync framework).